# MasterShaper alternative

Tags: linux, qos, traffic-shaping

I'm looking for an alternative to MasterShaper, something possibly web-based which could allow me to manage QoS *easily*. 
Actually MasterShaper still looks supported, but would like to understand if there's anything better. My forum account hasn't been activated since nearly one month!

Comment: What's wrong with mastershaper which makes you want something else?

Comment: I cannot access the forum to get support :( this looks to me like there's nobody caring

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm looking to implement something like MasterShaper but I was worried that, though there have been commits to its git repository this year, the last release package is from 2006.

Comment: I also found this blog post that isn't very encouraging: http://adrian.holfter.de/blog/en/2012/11/angetestet-mastershaper-auf-archlinux/